# How to edit specific item in KivyMD list?

Tags: python, kivymd

I'm trying to implement a feature that will allow user to edit any specific list items.

Currently, the code below does the following:

1. User can add a new entry in MDList and variable protocols by filling in Proc and Depth textinputs.
2. By clicking on any MDList entries they can remove it, and add value of Proc and Depths back to the TextInputs for correction
3. Button Edit then activated, which will add a new, corrected entry as the last one.

This code works alright if user wants to correct the last entry, as far as I checked then it works as intended.

But if the user tries to correct any than the last entry, everything messes up, due to Rod and Distance variables being automatically incremented by add_entry() function.

Is there anyway to do it correctly, and actually implement what I've intended? (remove any entry, correct it, and add it back where it was)

```
import re

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    GridLayout:
        cols:3
        GridLayout:
            id: testing
            cols:2
            MDLabel:
                text: '%:'
            TextInput:
                id: proc
                multiline: False
                input_type: 'number'
                input_filter: 'int'
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Depth:'
            TextInput:
                id: depth
                multiline: False
                input_type: 'number'
                input_filter: 'int'
        Button:
            id: add
            text: 'Add'
            on_release:
                app.add_entry(proc.text, depth.text)
                proc.text = ''
                depth.text = ''
        Button:
            id: edit
            text: 'Edit'
            disabled: True
            on_release:
                app.edit_entry(proc.text, depth.text, app.rod, app.dist)
                proc.text = ''
                depth.text = '' 
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: .5, .5
        MDList:
            id: container
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    rod = 1
    dist = 3
    protocol = list()  # {Rod:_,Distance:_,Proc:_,Depth:_}

    def edit_entry(self, proc, depth, rod, dist):
        """new_entry = OneLineListItem(text=f"Rod: {rod-1} Distance: {dist-3} Proc: {proc} Depth: {depth}",
                                    on_press=lambda x: self.change_entry(proc, depth, new_entry))"""
        self.protocol[-1] = {"Rod": rod-1, "Distance": dist-3, "Proc": proc, "Depth": depth}
        clean_entry = re.sub(r"[,'{}]", '', str(self.protocol[-1]))
        new_entry = OneLineListItem(text=clean_entry,
                                    on_press=lambda x: self.change_entry(proc, depth, new_entry))
        self.root.ids.container.add_widget(new_entry)
        self.root.ids.edit.disabled = True
        self.root.ids.add.disabled = False

    def change_entry(self, proc, depth, entry):
        self.root.ids.proc.text = proc
        self.root.ids.depth.text = depth
        self.root.ids.container.remove_widget(entry)
        self.root.ids.edit.disabled = False
        self.root.ids.add.disabled = True


    def add_entry(self, proc, depth):
        self.protocol.append({"Rod": '', "Distance": '', "Proc": '', "Depth": ''})
        self.protocol[self.rod - 1]["Proc"] = proc
        self.protocol[self.rod - 1]["Depth"] = depth
        self.protocol[self.rod - 1]["Rod"] = self.rod
        self.protocol[self.rod - 1]["Distance"] = self.dist
        clean_entry = re.sub(r"[,'{}]", '', str(self.protocol[self.rod - 1]))
        entry = OneLineListItem(text=f"{clean_entry}", on_press=lambda x: self.change_entry(proc, depth, entry))
        self.root.ids.container.add_widget(entry)
        self.rod += 1
        self.dist += 3

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)



Test().run()

print(Test.protocol)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove an entire widget (here `OneLineListItem`) in order to just change its contents. You can achieve that by accessing that specific widget, store it with a variable, apply whatever changes you want to that stored variable. Below is such an implementation,

```py
class Test(MDApp):
    selected_entry = ObjectProperty()
    # This will refer the entry 
    rod = 1
    dist = 3
    protocol = list()  # {Rod:_,Distance:_,Proc:_,Depth:_}

    def edit_entry(self, proc, depth, rod, dist):
        """new_entry = OneLineListItem(text=f"Rod: {rod-1} Distance: {dist-3} Proc: {proc} Depth: {depth}",
                                    on_press=lambda x: self.change_entry(proc, depth, new_entry))"""
        self.protocol[-1] = {"Rod": rod-1, "Distance": dist-3, "Proc": proc, "Depth": depth}
        clean_entry = re.sub(r"[,'{}]", '', str(self.protocol[-1]))
        # Just change the text.
        self.selected_entry.text = clean_entry
#        new_entry = OneLineListItem(text=clean_entry,
#                                    on_press=lambda x: self.change_entry(proc, depth, new_entry))
#        self.root.ids.container.add_widget(new_entry)
        self.root.ids.edit.disabled = True
        self.root.ids.add.disabled = False

    def change_entry(self, entry, proc, depth):
        # Here 'entry' is the widget that has been passed.
        self.root.ids.proc.text = proc
        self.root.ids.depth.text = depth
        # Store this entry to access it from anywhere in this class.
        self.selected_entry = entry
#        self.root.ids.container.remove_widget(entry)
        self.root.ids.edit.disabled = False
        self.root.ids.add.disabled = True


    def add_entry(self, proc, depth):
        self.protocol.append({"Rod": '', "Distance": '', "Proc": '', "Depth": ''})
        self.protocol[self.rod - 1]["Proc"] = proc
        self.protocol[self.rod - 1]["Depth"] = depth
        self.protocol[self.rod - 1]["Rod"] = self.rod
        self.protocol[self.rod - 1]["Distance"] = self.dist
        clean_entry = re.sub(r"[,'{}]", '', str(self.protocol[self.rod - 1]))
        entry = OneLineListItem(text=f"{clean_entry}", on_press=lambda x: self.change_entry(x, proc, depth))
        # Here 'x' is the widget that has to be passed on.
        self.root.ids.container.add_widget(entry)
        self.rod += 1
        self.dist += 3
```

Now you can maintain the order of appearance as well as their contents.

Comment: That's an easy and amazing way to do this! I was wondering if you can advise me on how to properly acquire the correct rod variable, so user can actually change any entry in the list, instead of the last one. I assume all I need to do is, somehow pass the correct rod variable when list item is being clicked. 

Thank you for always finding time to assist me with my inquiries, Apu!

Comment: Actually, I did figure it out, thanks to your example. I've made ObjectProperties for rod and dist, and assigned them values in the add_entry, then added them to lamda function and viola. Thanks again for the help! :)

Comment: If 'rod' & 'dist' happen to be just numbers, better use `NumericProperty`.

Comment: Alright, will do. Much appreciated advice